# Mock email payload on python

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

I'm writing unit tests for a function that should get all valid attachments in email message. My function has the following behaviour:

```
def extract_attachments(local_file):
    email_file = open(local_file, "r")
    msg = email.message_from_file(email_file)        
    attchs = [x for x in msg.get_payload() if x.get_filename() is not None]
    for attch in attchs:
        filename = attch.get_filename()
        if filename not in VALID_ATTACHMENTS:
            raise Exception('Invalid attachment', filename)        
    return attchs
```

How can I make this function return some object with a function `get_filename()`?

I'm trying to patch it but I'm getting an error `'list' object has no attribute 'get_payload'`.

```
@patch("mail_extractor.process_email.email")
@patch("builtins.open")
def test_extract_attachments(open, email):
    email.message_from_file.return_value = []
    email.get_payload.return_value = ['1.xml']
    result = process_email.extract_attachments('mock')
    assert len(result) == 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The notation you've described is specific to objects, and what you're trying to give it is a method. You'll need to define a class:

```
class MyClass:
    def get_filename():
        # some logic
```

Then you'll be able to instantiate your object:

```
x = MyClass()
x.get_filename()
```

Does that answer your question?

Comment: So I need to write a class to mock Email methods?

Comment: I think what you actually intended to do is this: `attchs = [msg for x in msg.get_payload() if msg.get_filename() is not None]`, that way you'll still have the msg objects, just filtered by the results of `get_filename`. I'm guessing that `get_payload()` returns a list, not an object.

Comment: I got that. Let me try one thing

Answer (score 0):

The way you've configured your mocks isn't quite right. The `message_from_file()` call needs to return a message, whereas you're returning a list - hence the error you're seeing.

You should set up a mock message along with a mock attachment in order to satisfy the calls the code expects to make.

For example:

```py
@patch("mail_extractor.process_email.email")
@patch("builtins.open")
def test_extract_attachments(open, email):
    # Configure the mock message and its attachment
    mock_message = Mock()
    mock_attachment = Mock()
    mock_attachment.get_filename.return_value = '1.xml'
    mock_message.get_payload.return_value = [mock_attachment]

    # Configure message_from_file to return the mock message
    email.message_from_file.return_value = mock_message

    result = process_email.extract_attachments('mock')
    assert len(result) == 1
```